# hard drive partations mount problem

Tags: mount, ntfs

When I tried to access my partition then I found the following message:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda4 at /media/pc/16564B1C564AFBCD: 
Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda4" "/media/pc/16564B1C564AFBCD"' 
exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.   
Failed to mount '/dev/sda4': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume read-only with the 'ro' mount option."
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Well, do as it says: shut down Ubuntu, start up Windows, then shutdown Windows without hibernating. Then start up Ubuntu again.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably bcoz of fast boot in windows.

You have to first disable fast boot up feature in windows.

follow this guide to disable it - http://www.typicaltips.com/2013/02/disable-fast-startup-in-windows-8.html

and after start ubuntu and now you can use your partion